# I need some guidance understanding how ActionListener and actionPerformed(ActionEvent) work

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm teaching myself about Java's swing components, and have run into a little conceptual snag. I'm sure that I've got some of the specific terminology wrong, but hopefully I'm communicating my difficulties well enough to get an answer or two.

I have the following code, stripped down for brevity:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
//
public class CreateButtonSel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ButtonSel thisButtonSel = new ButtonSel();
        final int WIDTH = 250;
        final int HEIGHT = 250;
        thisButtonSel.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        thisButtonSel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When I add in the `implements ActionListener` (commented out below) I get an error that `ButtonSel is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`. From what I've read in the javadocs and on various sites, I'm gathering that the error is a result of not having already defined the action in a method. Something like

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clickButton) {
     do stuff;
     {
```

However, I'm not clear on where that method needs to live. I'm GUESSING that it lives in the `ButtonSel` class with the constructor--because that's where I'm defining the button object. However, I can also see it as a method in the `CreateButtonSel` class, and getting passed to `ButtonSel` as a parameter. Then, there's the question of how or if these button action characteristics are passed to the constructor? Or are they automatically appended to the button object created by the constructor if they're in the `CreateButtonSel` class?

Can someone please explain how the program flow is supposed to work and what calls which method when?

```
//    public class ButtonSel extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
public class ButtonSel extends JFrame {
    JButton approveButton = new JButton("Go");
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
 //
    public ButtonSel() {
        super("ButtonTest");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(approveButton);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How to Write an ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for one example. You can also search the forum for other working examples.